# Clean Url problems WIth ubuntu apache , php-fpm, fastcgi

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, fastcgi, drupal, php-fpm

Well this is a kind of repost of [this](http://drupal.org/node/1235890), but no one has replied to my question so far, so I am here.

I am using Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi with php-fpm and I can't enable clean URLs as the site returns Internal Server Errors . I think something is not right in my .htaccess settings. The same server contains Wordpress under a different virtual host and it works fine.

This is some relevant information that I hope can help to find out the problem.

My virtual host contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/dowsin/public_html
    FastCgiExternalServer /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external -host 127.0.0.1:9000
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.external
    Alias /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ /home/dowsin/public_html/
    RewriteLog "/home/dowsin/public_html/rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 9

    <Directory "/home/dowsin/public_html">
        allow from all
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess contains

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**rewrite_log**:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/user -> user
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'user'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/user' pattern='!-f' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/user' pattern='!-d' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] rewrite 'user' -> 'index.php?q=user'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (3) split uri=index.php?q=user -> uri=index.php, args=q=user
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/dowsin/public_html/ with /
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b828f3c0/initial] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8294ce8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8294ce8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8294ce8/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8294ce8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] pass through /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external -> /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php -> php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-f' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-d' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] rewrite 'php5.external/index.php' -> 'index.php?q=php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (3) split uri=index.php?q=php5.external/index.php -> uri=index.php, args=q=php5.external/index.php&q=user
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/dowsin/public_html/ with /
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b8299248/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829b7e0/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829b7e0/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829b7e0/initial/redir#3] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829b7e0/initial/redir#3] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] pass through /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external -> /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php -> php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-f' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-d' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] rewrite 'php5.external/index.php' -> 'index.php?q=php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (3) split uri=index.php?q=php5.external/index.php -> uri=index.php, args=q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=user
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/dowsin/public_html/ with /
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829caa0/initial/redir#4] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829f128/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829f128/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829f128/initial/redir#5] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b829f128/initial/redir#5] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] pass through /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external -> /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php -> php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-f' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-d' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] rewrite 'php5.external/index.php' -> 'index.php?q=php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (3) split uri=index.php?q=php5.external/index.php -> uri=index.php, args=q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=user
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/dowsin/public_html/ with /
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a05f0/initial/redir#6] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a2dd0/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a2dd0/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a2dd0/initial/redir#7] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a2dd0/initial/redir#7] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] pass through /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external -> /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php -> php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-f' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-d' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] rewrite 'php5.external/index.php' -> 'index.php?q=php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (3) split uri=index.php?q=php5.external/index.php -> uri=index.php, args=q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=user
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/dowsin/public_html/ with /
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a4348/initial/redir#8] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a6c78/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a6c78/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a6c78/initial/redir#9] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a6c78/initial/redir#9] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] pass through /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add path info postfix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external -> /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external/index.php -> php5.external/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-f' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (4) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] RewriteCond: input='/home/dowsin/public_html/php5.external' pattern='!-d' => matched
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] rewrite 'php5.external/index.php' -> 'index.php?q=php5.external/index.php'
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (3) split uri=index.php?q=php5.external/index.php -> uri=index.php, args=q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=php5.external/index.php&q=user
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (2) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] trying to replace prefix /home/dowsin/public_html/ with /
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (5) strip matching prefix: /home/dowsin/public_html/index.php -> index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Aug/2011:14:54:07 +0000] [example.com/sid#b80e52b0][rid#b82a8338/initial/redir#10] (1) [perdir /home/dowsin/public_html/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

**Server error log**:

[Mon Aug 01 15:59:20 2011] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

**Wordpress Blog settings : vhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.com
ServerAlias www.blog.com
DocumentRoot /home/rod32/public_html
FastCgiExternalServer /home/rod32/public_html/php5.external -host 127.0.0.1:9000
AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.external
Alias /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ /home/rod32/public_html/

RewriteLogLevel 3
<Directory "/home/rod32/public_html">
allow from all
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/home/rod32/error.log"
CustomLog "/home/rod32/access.log" combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Your logs and config are very hard to read. Instead of using blockquote, I'd consider using the code block for those - it will come out better.

Comment: Sorry for that edited :)

Comment: There you go, I've also touched up some other bits too :-)

Comment: How about posting the VirtualHost / .htaccess for the working Wordpress install?

Comment: Level 3 is too low to see what is going on -- please use Level 9 and supply your rewrite log again (no need full log -- at least first 2 redirects): `RewriteLogLevel 9`.

Comment: In any case -- I think you should add one more condition to ignore rewrite of `php5.external`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !php5\.external`

Comment: Updated log with RewriteLogLevel 9, and added wordpress vhost settings

Comment: This is what I see from logs -- it rewrites request to `/user` to `/index.php?q=user` just fine and then it goes to next iteration. On 2nd iteration no rewrite of `/index.php?q=user` occurs (because of conditions) .. and then it tries to execute/rewrite `php5.external` .. and this is where rewrite loop begins. I'm pretty sure that adding one more condition (to prevent rewriting of `php5.external`) will do the job.

Comment: Thanks it works need to add **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !php5\.external**
To .htaccess file but i wonder why this problem doesn't effect the wordpress blog. I am really noob to url rewriting

Comment: @user80287 _"but i wonder why this problem doesn't effect the wordpress blog"_ -- for that you need to enable rewrite debugging and see what is going on inside -- that is the best way.

Comment: @LazyOne - If I were you, I'd post your solution as an answer so you can gain upvotes for it.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't find a better solution but puting this on the conds into yours .htacces do the trick

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !php5.external
```

Or somethinf like this cond!

It worked on my drupal testes... but i am looking for something that can work without i have to edit all .htacess from my server